# Antd: Dynamic Form + pre tab

Tags: antd

Using Ant Design, I'm trying to build a [Dynamic Form](https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-items), where each Form Item consists of a single input field with a [pre tab](https://ant.design/components/input#components-input-demo-addon).

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/hpemolly/pen/NWoLoda?editors=0011) showing where I'm at so far. I've got dynamic form, and I've got the input with pre tab, but I haven't yet been able to make it such that the pre tab data is reported in `onFinish()`

```js
"use strict";
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } = icons;
const { Button, Form, Input, Select } = antd;
const App = () => {
    const onFinish = (values) => {
        console.log("Received values of form:", values);
    };
    return (React.createElement(Form, { name: "dynamic_form_item", onFinish: onFinish, style: {
            maxWidth: 600
        } },
        React.createElement(Form.List, { name: "names" }, (fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (React.createElement(React.Fragment, null,
            fields.map((field, index) => (React.createElement(Form.Item, { required: false, key: field.key },
                React.createElement(Form.Item, Object.assign({}, field, { rules: [
                        {
                            required: true,
                            whitespace: true,
                            message: "Please input a filter or delete this field."
                        }
                    ], noStyle: true }),
                    React.createElement(Input, { placeholder: "filter", addonBefore: 
                        //<Form.Item name="prefix" noStyle>
                        React.createElement(Select, { popupMatchSelectWidth: false, listHeight: 1000, defaultValue: "LIKE", options: [
                                { label: "LIKE", value: "LIKE" },
                                { label: "NOT LIKE", value: "NOT LIKE" },
                                { label: "=", value: "=" },
                                { label: "!=", value: "!=" },
                                { label: "BETWEEN", value: "BETWEEN" },
                                { label: ">", value: ">" },
                                { label: "<", value: "<" },
                                { label: ">=", value: ">=" },
                                { label: "<=", value: "<=" }
                            ] }) })),
                React.createElement(MinusCircleOutlined, { onClick: () => remove(field.name) })))),
            React.createElement(Form.Item, null,
                React.createElement(Button, { onClick: () => add(), icon: React.createElement(PlusOutlined, null) }, "Add field"),
                React.createElement(Form.ErrorList, { errors: errors }))))),
        React.createElement(Form.Item, null,
            React.createElement(Button, { type: "primary", htmlType: "submit" }, "Submit"))));
};
const ComponentDemo = App;
createRoot(mountNode).render(React.createElement(ComponentDemo, null));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Dynamic Form Item - antd@5.11.5</title>
  

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="container" style="padding: 24px" />
          <script>const mountNode = document.getElementById('container');</script>
        </body>
      </html>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/antd@5.11.5/dist/antd-with-locales.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@ant-design/icons/dist/index.umd.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.production.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router/dist/umd/react-router.production.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any field that you want to connect with form, use `name` prop in `Form.Item`. In `name`, you can pass the complete `NamePath`, how value should be stored in form. For example, if namePath is `name='prefix'` then form values object will look like `{ prefix: <value> }`. In your case, each list item has two fields. So for each field, namePath will be like this `name={[field.name, 'prefix']}`. Note that type of field.name is number. So it acts as an index in Form.List and `prefix` becomes the key of an object at that particular index. Form.List automatically adds the list `name` with child fields. For more details, you can follow antd form list examples and api section.

Note that i removed `defaultValue` prop from select. When `name` prop is used, the component (in your case `Select` component) becomes controlled field, so `defaultValue` will not work. In order to set default value, you need to use `initialValues` but for dynamic list it cannot be used. [Form.List](https://ant.design/components/form#operation) provide `add` function to create a new item but you can also set default value for new item like this `add({ prefix: 'LIKE' })`.

Here's the complete code

```
import { Button, Form, Input, Select } from 'antd';
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const options = [
    { label: 'LIKE', value: 'LIKE' },
    { label: 'NOT LIKE', value: 'NOT LIKE' },
    { label: '=', value: '=' },
    { label: '!=', value: '!=' },
    { label: 'BETWEEN', value: 'BETWEEN' },
    { label: '>', value: '>' },
    { label: '<', value: '<' },
    { label: '>=', value: '>=' },
    { label: '<=', value: '<=' }
];

const App = () => {
    const onFinish = (values) => {
        console.log('Received values of form:', values);
    };
    return (
        <Form name='dynamic_form_item' onFinish={onFinish} style={{ maxWidth: 600 }}>
            <Form.List name='names'>
                {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
                    <>
                        {fields.map((field) => (
                            <div key={field.key} style={{ display: 'flex', columnGap: 8, marginBottom: 8 }}>
                                <Form.Item
                                    name={[field.name, 'value']}
                                    rules={[{ required: true, whitespace: true, message: 'Please input a filter or delete this field.' }]}
                                    noStyle
                                >
                                    <Input
                                        placeholder='filter'
                                        addonBefore={
                                            <Form.Item name={[field.name, 'prefix']} noStyle>
                                                <Select popupMatchSelectWidth={false} listHeight={1000} options={options} />
                                            </Form.Item>
                                        }
                                    />
                                </Form.Item>
                                <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(field.name)} />
                            </div>
                        ))}
                        <Form.Item>
                            <Button onClick={() => add({ prefix: 'LIKE' })} icon={<PlusOutlined />}>
                                Add field
                            </Button>
                            <Form.ErrorList errors={errors} />
                        </Form.Item>
                    </>
                )}
            </Form.List>
            <Form.Item>
                <Button type='primary' htmlType='submit'>
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    );
};

export default App;
```